# Sample Casper JS Script does not work

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

UPDATE: I found the solution and I forgot to add

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
```

on the top.

The original question:
I installed phantom js 1.9.2 and casper js 1.0.3. Additionally I copy and pasted the follwing sample script directly from the casper js tutorial page:

```
casper.start('http://www.google.fr/', function() {
    var url = 'http://www.google.fr/intl/fr/about/corporate/company/';
    this.download(url, 'google_company.html');
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('Done.').exit();
});
```

This is the output on my mac os lion:

```
bin Tom$ ./casperjs ../site_loader.js 
2013-11-26 18:53:20.375 phantomjs[2136:130b] *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead. 
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: casper

  ../site_loader.js:1
Hint: you may want to use the `casperjs test` command.
^C
```

I have to manually cancel it otherwise it will never stop. However running the suggested command yields:

```
bin Tom$ ./casperjs test
2013-11-26 18:54:01.504 phantomjs[2137:130b] *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead. 
No test path passed, exiting.
```

What is not correct here?

Comment: The example is for version 1.1.0-dev
If you update, you will need to remove the `var casper = require('casper').create();`, otherwise the program won't exit because the `casperjs test` command will provide that call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very first of all, you need to create a [casper](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#casper-module) instance to work with, then everything you have written will work!

```
// sample.js
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://www.google.fr/', function() {
    var url = 'http://www.google.fr/intl/fr/about/corporate/company/';
    this.download(url, 'google_company.html');
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('Done.').exit();
});
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\hello\Desktop>caperjs sample.js
Done.

C:\Users\hello\Desktop>ls -alt
-rwx------ hello mkpasswd 91 Nov 28 09:11 google_company.html 
...
```

Comment: And now you think you get a +1 for your "answer", that is basically just what I already added on top of my question _before_ you answered?

Comment: @toom Just let you know, I was keeping an eye on your post yesterday and did not get a chance to answer until moments ago.. Did not pay attention to your update and sorry for the confusion. I will delete my posts once your received this message. Good luck with scraping.

Comment: @toom Just out of curiosity, what is the reason made you prefer phantomJS/casper over other tools like (Python/Selenium). I personally doesn't have that much experience with JS and wondering should I spend more time on it and it will bring me something amazing :)

Comment: Well, I'm far from being an expert in this js stuff. However, afaik there does not exist any headless browser besides this phantomjs that is fully capable of js. I mean phantomjs is a webkit browser without ui. And it enables me to load rather "complicated" sites, that use subsequent ajax requests to load additional stuff. Those site are very  hard to scrape. However on the downside PhantomJS is very slow.